# MongoDB GroupBy SUM with filter in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am getting group by the result using below aggregation pipeline, but I want to add a filter in sum on a boolean value, I am using below code and Need to correct the `IsResponseRecieved` line in code.

```js
var group = new BsonDocument
{
  {
    "$group",
      new BsonDocument
    {
      { "_id", new BsonDocument{ { "Class", "$Class" } } },
      { "TotaRecords", new BsonDocument{ { "$sum", 1 } } },
      { "RequestTime", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$RequestTime") },
      { "ProcessTime", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$ProcessTime") },
      { "AvgRequestTime", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$RequestTime") },
      { "AvProcessTime", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$ProcessTime") },
      { "IsResponseRecieved", new BsonDocument("$sum", { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$IsResponseRecieved", false] }, 1, 0] } })
    }
  }
}
};
var pipeline = new [] { group };
var res = LogDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tblLogs").Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest approach would be to just parse that blob of json in to a BSON document with the following code

```cs
var group = new BsonDocument
           {
                {
                    "$group",
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "_id", new BsonDocument{ { "Class", "$Class" } } },
                        { "TotaRecords", new BsonDocument{ { "$sum", 1 } } },
                        { "RequestTime", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$RequestTime") },
                        { "ProcessTime", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$ProcessTime") },
                        { "AvgRequestTime", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$RequestTime") },
                        { "AvProcessTime", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$ProcessTime") },
                        { "IsResponseRecieved", new BsonDocument("$sum", BsonDocument.Parse(@"{ $cond: [{ $eq: [""$IsResponseRecieved"", false]}, 1, 0] }")) }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Alternative you can create a typed bson document like the following:

```cs
var isResponseRecieved = new BsonDocument("$cond",
    new BsonArray(new BsonValue[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$eq",
            new BsonArray(new BsonValue[]{ "$IsResponseRecieved" , false})), 
        1, 
        0
    }));
var group = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$group",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", new BsonDocument{ { "Class", "$Class" } } },
            { "TotaRecords", new BsonDocument{ { "$sum", 1 } } },
            { "RequestTime", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$RequestTime") },
            { "ProcessTime", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$ProcessTime") },
            { "AvgRequestTime", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$RequestTime") },
            { "AvProcessTime", new BsonDocument("$avg", "$ProcessTime") },
            { "IsResponseRecieved", isResponseRecieved }
        }
    }
};
```